# SQL AVG on a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table

[image]

I am trying to get the average price for each prod_type_desc, i have the following code that gets me here, but cant figure out the rest.

```
select * from (select price, prod_type_desc from products NATURAL JOIN producttypes NATURAL JOIN refproducttypes) as a
```

i have tried `select AVG(price), prod_type_desc from above` but that does not work.

Comment: Thanks for showing sample data. In future, please do it with *text* not a screenshot, though - even better, `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements. Remember to mention your PostgreSQL version in questions too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `GROUP BY` on the `product_type_desc`

```
select prod_type_desc, avg(price) from products group by prod_type_desc
```

Comment: Thanks I cant believe I was only missing the group by

Comment: You must include a group by when you're using aggregate functions along with selecting columns normally.

Answer (score 0):

This statement should work,

```
select prod_type_price, avg(price) from products group by prod_type_price
```